# SQL - Find the next row ID in sequence

Tags: sql, mysql, sequence

I have two tables TESTS and TESTS_ATTEMPTED. I am trying to output the ID for the next test to be taken in each test type (maths, english, science) for a given USER_ID.

The structure of the tables is as follows (with some sample data):

```
TESTS
================
 ID    TEST_NAME   TEST_TYPE
  1     Science 1   Science
  2     Maths 1     Maths
  3     Maths 2     Maths
  4     Science 2   Science

TESTS_ATTEMPTED
================
ID   TEST_ID   USER_ID 
 1     1          2 
 2     1          1 
 3     2          2  
 4     3          2
```

An SQL fiddle with this dummy data is here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43efb/2

The expected result would be (for user ID 2):

```
TEST_TYPE   NUM_TESTS   NUM_TAKEN   NEXT_TEST_ID    
Science       2            1         4
Maths         2            2         Null
```

I have been able to create a query with the number of tests taken by a user, but not sure if it is possible to output the next test type?

```
SELECT count(*) as num_tests_taken, 
    TEST_NAME from TEST_NAMES tn 
INNER JOIN TESTS_ATTEMPTED ta on tn.ID = ta.TEST_ID AND ta.USER_ID = 2 
GROUP BY tn.ID
```

How might I join the queries together and also output the next TEST ID to be taken?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this different from the last question you asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917976/sql-find-number-of-joining-rows-and-next-row-id-in-sequence

Comment: Hi @Strawberry - This one is more specific and hopefully clearer

Comment: Nooo. Just delete this one, clarify the old one, and then add a comment to it (so, in the comments section) just mentioning that that's what you've done.

Comment: i'd say your datamodel is going to make life difficult for you. predicting the next ID in a multi user system is going to be very difficult to get working correctly. A much better approach is to wait until you need to create the next test attempt then within a transaction block grab the id that was created for you. alternativly if you need gapless ids increment this yourself in a transaction block. in your approach multiple user could have id 4 as the ne t id which should not be possible. assuming id is also your PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TEST_TYPE, COUNT(*) AS NUM_TESTS, COUNT(TEST_ID) AS NUM_TAKEN, (
        SELECT MIN(tn.ID)
        FROM TESTS tn
        LEFT JOIN TESTS_ATTEMPTED ta ON tn.ID = ta.TEST_ID
            AND ta.USER_ID = 2
        WHERE otn.TEST_TYPE = tn.TEST_TYPE
            AND ta.USER_ID IS NULL
        GROUP BY TEST_TYPE
        ) AS NEXT_TEST_ID
FROM TESTS otn
LEFT JOIN TESTS_ATTEMPTED ota ON otn.ID = ota.TEST_ID
    AND ota.USER_ID = 2
GROUP BY TEST_TYPE
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43efb/26/0)</kbd>